# calculate a mean by criteria in R

Tags: r, mean

I would like to calculate a sample mean in R by introducing a specific criteria. For example I have this table and I want the means of only those for whom stage = 1 or 2:

```
treatment session period stage wage_accepted type 
1            1      1     1            25  low 
1            1      1     3            19  low 
1            1      1     3            15  low 
1            1      1     2            32 high 
1            1      1     2            13  low 
1            1      1     2            14  low 
1            1      2     1            17  low 
1            1      2     4            16  low
1            1      2     5            21  low
```

The desired out in this case should be:

```
   stage  mean
      1  21.0 
      2  19.6667
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the `dplyr` library

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% filter(stage==1 | stage ==2) %>% group_by(stage) %>%
  summarise(mean=mean(wage_accepted))
```

If you are new to `dplyr` a bit of explanation:

Take the data frame `df` then `filter` where `stage` is equal to 1 or 2. Then for each `group` in `stage` calculate the `mean` of the `wage_accepted`

Comment: Thanks, it's useful. However my data is really big in fact and the above is just an example. I would like to choose 25 answers of a variable which has 50. In this case (filter stage==1 | .... | stage == 25) would be a little bit long. How can I do it more efficiently?

Comment: Use `filter(stage %in% 1:25)`

Comment: it is in qualitative not in quantitative. The answers are for example 'A', 'B', 'C' and so on...

Comment: Yeap, you got the logic!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have a csv file for the data, you can read data into a data frame using:

```
data<-read.csv("PATH_TO_YOUR_CSV_FILE/Name_of_the_CSV_File.csv")
```

Then you can use either this code relying on `sapply()`:

```
sapply(split(data$Wage_Accepted,data$Stage),mean)

   1        2        3        4        5 
21.00000 19.66667 17.00000 16.00000 21.00000
```

Or this code relying on `tapply()`:

```
tapply(data$Wage_Accepted,data$Stage,mean)

   1        2        3        4        5 
21.00000 19.66667 17.00000 16.00000 21.00000
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this out. It's a toy example, but data.table is so compact. dplyr is great as well obviously.

```
    library(data.table)

    dat <- data.table(iris)
    dat[Species == "setosa" | Species == "virginica", mean(Sepal.Width), by = Species]
```

In terms of your need for speed... data.table is a rocket ship look it up. I'll leave it to you to apply this to your question. Best, M2K

Answer (score 0):

You can do this and then later filter for Stages as per your requirement

```
# Calculating mean with respect to stages
df = do.call(rbind, lapply(split(data, f = data$stage),function(x) out = data.frame(stage = unique(x$stage), mean = mean(x$wage_accepted))))

# mean for stage 1 and 2
required = subset(df, stage %in% c(1,2))
```