# Calculate mean down a column by an interval in R

Tags: r

I was unable to find a duplicate of my question, so I hope you can help.

Using a simple example, I wish to calculate mean/average down a column, based on a specified window size (calling it `n`).

```
data <- data.frame(x = rep(1:10,1), y = rep(11:20, 1))
```

I wish to add a column `z`, which calculates the average of 4 rows at a time.

So result will be:

```
structure(list(x = 1:10, y = 11:20, z = c("NA", "NA", "NA", "12.5", 
"13.5", "14.5", "15.5", "16.5", "17.5", "18.5")), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("x", 
"y", "z"), row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

I calculated row averages down a column, in intervals of n rows as follows:

```
#For n = 4, row 4 is calculated as (11+12+13+14)/n
#For n =4, row 5 is calculated as (12+13+14+15)/n
#And so on ...
```

I looked at following posts such as:

1. [how to calculate combined column mean value in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52941895/how-to-calculate-combined-column-mean-value-in-r)
2. [Calculate mean by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33088702/calculate-mean-by-group)
3. [How to calculate average of a variable by hour in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24645628/how-to-calculate-average-of-a-variable-by-hour-in-r)
4. [Calculate the mean of every 13 rows in data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30359427/calculate-the-mean-of-every-13-rows-in-data-frame)
5. [calculate a mean by criteria in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29724286/calculate-a-mean-by-criteria-in-r)

I attempted this code below, but I am unable to obtain the write solutions.

```
data<-data %>% mutate(z=rollapplyr(y,10,FUN=mean,by=4))
```

Appreciate your help. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using rolling mean of library zoo

```
data <- data.frame(x = rep(1:10,1), y = rep(11:20, 1))

result <- structure(list(x = 1:10, y = 11:20, z = c("NA", "NA", "NA", "12.5", 
                                                    "13.5", "14.5", "15.5", "16.5", "17.5", "18.5")), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("x", 
                                                                                                                                       "y", "z"), row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

## Answer

```
library(zoo)
data$z <- rollmeanr(data$y,4,fill=NA)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `outer()` with a customized function. The `diag()` gives you the desired values.

```
myMean <- function(x, y) mean(dat[seq(x, y), 2])
mmean <- diag(outer(1:nrow(dat), (4:nrow(dat)), Vectorize(myMean)))

dat$z <- NA  # initialize column
dat$z[-(1:3)] <- mmean

#     x  y    z
# 1   1 11   NA
# 2   2 12   NA
# 3   3 13   NA
# 4   4 14 12.5
# 5   5 15 13.5
# 6   6 16 14.5
# 7   7 17 15.5
# 8   8 18 16.5
# 9   9 19 17.5
# 10 10 20 18.5
```

***Data***

```
dat <- data.frame(x=rep(1:10, 1), y=rep(11:20, 1))
```